# Compile C++ 11 on Damn Small Linux?

Tags: compile, c++, g++, damn-small-linux

DSL does not include any compiler (aside from a very basic ANSI C compiler), so I need to install g++ on it. Unfortunately the only gcc/g++ I could find for DSL linux is a version from 2006 ([here](http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/mydsl/system/)).
How can I get a recent version of g++ on DSL?
I tried compiling a "hello world" program on Ubuntu 13.04 with g++ 4.9.something just to test out whether it runs on DSL, but it does't.

So either a cross-compiling solution, or a recent version of g++ working on DSL would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that DSL uses an old linux kernel (2.4 if I remember correctly) so it's pretty much impossible to have a C++ 11 compiler on it. I changed to Tiny Core linux, since that's a very similar distro, but it uses a much more modern kernel which enables lots of things (including more modern compilers).